# Overloading the IPhone "GO" button to perform an action

Tags: iphone, keyboard, overloading

I am designing an application using html and javascript. I have a login form with a Login button on it. A textfield accepts a username and then pressing the login button, login action takes place. However, what i want to do now is that while using the virtual keypad in IPhone, clicking the GO button must initiate the Login action too.
Please let me know the solution for the same.
Thanks.

Comment: did you find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Set a delegate object (point to your view controller) for your UITextField and use the method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

-textFieldShouldReturn will be called just before the user the user taps the "Go" or "Return". Remember to return "YES".

Comment: You have got, what I want to do.....But its not exactly what I mean. My text field where user enters username is HTML control, so I can not give focus to UITextField if I included it. And hence tell me something that would detect GO click in javascript and I will be able to initiate with LOGIN process........