# Iphone default KeyBoard "Go" button action not working with PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, cordova, keyboard

I am using **PhoneGap 1.8.1** to build an application in Iphone.

I have an login window (screen shot attached below).

There are two html Text-boxes (one for entering user name and another one for entering password) and a Log-in button to login.

I can able to successfully Login through my Login button using  below code.

```
<input type="button" value="Login" id="btnSubmit" class="blueButton" data-role="none"/>

$("#btnLogin").click(function(){  

    var username = $("#txtUsername").val(); 
    var password = $("#txtPassword").val();
           //do login actions ….
});
```

I have to trigger the same Login functionality when user taps on iPhone  Keyboard "Go" button.
However , I am unable to trigger the Login button actions while user taps on the iOS default Keyboard "Go" button.

May i know how can i register/trigger the keyboard "Go" button event in PhoneGap.

I have found the related post in [Overloading the IPhone “GO” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667247/overloading-the-iphone-go-button-to-perform-an-action)

However i didn't find any good answer for that one.

Any help on this issue is Appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Log-in Screen]

Comment: try changing your button type to `submit` or you can also capture the form submit event instead of button click event

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...let me to check

Comment: did you try both option?? or which one??

Comment: i have done the code http://pastebin.com/2tbfEft1  However  login() not triggered...

Comment: you code looks and works fine in my current setup of cordova 1.7.0, checking with 1.8.1 now

Comment: what happened dude.. any hope??

Comment: could you please send me the code or Sample application link.. or mail me the sample application zip shamsutk87@gmail.com . Also please paste the code as Answer.Then i can Accept you answer if it helps me :)

Comment: Also if possible, please online in chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap  then in can communicate with ease with u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making your button of type `submit`

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnSubmit" class="blueButton" data-role="none"/>
```

Or bind event on form submit

```
$("#loginForm").form(function(){  
    // do event prevention if required

    var username = $("#txtUsername").val(); 
    var password = $("#txtPassword").val();
           //do login actions ….
});
```

Although this issue does not seem related to Phonegap (Cordova) as it should work same in browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, but couldn't change my button into a submit - I was using a trigger on click of an img.

But I found that even without a submit button, you can still register the form submit fired by the user clicking the "GO" button, and then do what you need to do.

```
$(document).on('submit', ".search-form", function(){
     runSearch(inputs);                                
});
```

I am not sure what would happen if you had multiple forms on a page, but this works for a single form.