# handle android go button using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, android-keypad

Am working in HTML5 and PhoneGap. Currently am facing an issue ; I couldn't handle the **GO** button of Android softkeyboad.
My Functionality is that; I have a Login button and when i enter password and click on the **GO** button of the keyboard it will be process the same function of Submit Button in my page. like in the Screen shot [image]

Is there any solution for this?? When Trying like my latest code event is working but jQUERY AJAX calling is not working. :(

**.. HTML code ..**

```
  <div data-role="page" id="page_login">
  <div data-role="header" id="header_login">
  <img src="images/loginheaderlogo.png" id="login_header_logo"><br/>
  <img src="images/loginheaderarrow.png" id="login_header_arrow">
  </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content_login" class="max_width scrolling">
    <form onsubmit="userLogin()"> <!--form submit-->
    <div id="login_textbox_container">
    <span class="valid" id="username_valid"></span>
    <img src="images/loginusericon.png" id="login_text_icon">
    <label class="input">
    <span>Username</span>
    <input type="text" id="input_usersername">
    </label>
    </div>
    <div id="login_textbox_container"><span class="valid" id="password_valid"></span>
    <img src="images/loginpassicon.png" id="login_text_icon">
    <label class="input">
    <span>Password</span>
    <input type="number" id="input_password">
    </label>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:37px">
    <div class="main_button"  id="login_button">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center">LOGIN</div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnSubmit" data-role="none"/>                    
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**.. JS code ..**

```
    $("#login_button").on( 'click', function(event) {
    userLogin();
    });
```

**.. Ajax Call ..**

```
    function userLogin() {
  var varData = 'username='+$('#input_usersername').val()+'&password='+$('#input_password').val();
var Validation_result = UserLogin_Validation()
if(Validation_result == true) {
$(".pre_loader").show();
setTimeout (function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://xxx.xx.net/authenticate.php',
    data: varData,
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        userToken=data.token;
        localStorage.removeItem("TOKEN");
        localStorage.setItem("TOKEN",userToken);
        if(userToken!=0)
        {
            var query=[$('#input_usersername').val(),$('#input_password').val(),userToken,timeStamp];

            obj.insertLogin(query);
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Invalid User')
            $(".pre_loader").hide();
        }
    },
    error: OnError
});
},1000);}
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394607/iphone-default-keyboard-go-button-action-not-working-with-phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the 'go' button only works for submitting [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

I do not see a form in your html.

```
<form onsubmit="userLogin()">
    <label>username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value= "submit">submit my form</form>
</form>
```

---

**Edit**

I have a working example: http://jsbin.com/IgeHUdEz/edit
I have stripped the HTML somewhat, but please note at how you should use labels with the for attribute.

*HTML*

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_login">
    <form id="loginform" name="login"> <!--form submit-->
        <label class="input" for="input_usersername">
            <span>Username</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="input_usersername">
        <label class="input" for="input_password">
            <span>Password</span>
        </label>
        <input type="number" id="input_password">
        <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:37px">
            <div class="main_button"  id="login_button"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Login" id="btnSubmit" data-role="none"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>                   
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$("#loginform").on( 'submit', function(event) {
  userLogin();
});

function userLogin() {
  alert($('#input_usersername').val() + " - " + $('#input_password').val());
}
```

Comment: Hi.. have a doubt.. in Action what i want to given? my current function is userLogin() so how can i call that ?

Comment: that was just a classic representation of a form, you can probably leave the action and method attributes out and use `<form onsubmit="userLogin()">` see the link rynhe gave

Comment: Hi @ Daniël Tulp :
Here our Ajax calling is not working.. now when we click on GO button; its goes to the userLogin Function but jQuery ajax calling not working.. is there any solution ?

Comment: have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394607/iphone-default-keyboard-go-button-action-not-working-with-phonegap ? if yes and you still can't work it out, please post your code (including js) in an edit

Comment: Can u please check my latest code? i have updated my latest one !

Comment: Its working.. but When jQueryAjax calls cmes ; its fails. Page just refresh and Ajax calling is not done ! :(

Comment: that sounds like a problem not related to your original question

Comment: I had a problem with this until I spotted I needed type=submit not just type=button

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, alternate answer if you don't want to use forms.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    document.getElementById('pwd').addEventListener('keypress',CheckKeyPress);
};

CheckKeyPress = function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        userLogin(); 
    }
}
```